# Any one help me on how to configure my hive to accept File formats like zlib, LZO , LZ4 and snappy compression

Tags: hadoop, compression, hive, azure-hdinsight, lz4

We are working on POC to figure out which compression technique is better to use for saving for file in compressed format and have better performance from compress format. we have 4 format *.gz, *.zlib, *.snappy & *.lz4.

We figured out *.gz and *.zlib has better compression ratio but they have performance issue while reading compressed, since these files are not splittable and Number of Mappers , reducers are always 1. These formats are default accepted by Hive 0.14.

but we want to test other compression technique for our text file like *.lz4, *.lzo and snappy

Can any one help me on how to configure my hive to read input file which is compressed in   *.lzo, snappy and *.lz4 and also Avro.

is these compress technique are present hive 0.14 or should i need to upload these *.jar ( i'm .NET Guys no idea on java) and use Serde for Serialisation and deserialization.

Can any one help me whether Hive by default accept those file format like *.lzo, *.snappy and *.lz4 and avro for reading these compressed file and should i need to configure hive to read these file format. I'm looking for best performance while reading of compressed file format. Its ok to compromise on Compression ratio, but should have better performance reading.

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using? LZO is GPL so it doesn't ship with Hadoop and is a tiny bit harder to implement. All the others you mentioned already ship with Hadoop and should be supported already. I also recommend that you use LZ4 since it has the same compression ratio as LZO but is faster to compress and decompress.

Comment: Avro is not a compression codec - it's a binary file format that has optional Snappy or deflate compression.